# Limits with parameters using a Taylor polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We are asked to discuss the existance and values of the following limit with $\mathbb{N} \ni n,m \geq 1$:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{{\left ( \left (1+x \right )^{\frac{1}{2}} -1 -\frac{x}{2} \right )}^{6m}} {{x^n}}}$$

We thought about calculating the $k$-th order Taylor polynomial around $0$ of $(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and discussing the limits with that, but we're not getting anywhere.

Comment: This is what youneed to do. Focus on $ \left(1+x \right )^{\frac{1}{2}} -1 -\frac{x}{2} $ first and then raise to power $6m$ and then divide by $x^n$. What do you get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order two Taylor polynomial is
$$
\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}+o(x^2)
$$
and therefore your expression is
$$
\frac{x^{12m}/2^{18m}+o(x^{12m})}{x^n}
$$
You should be able to finish, now.

Answer (score 0):

Defining $\sqrt{x+1}=t$ we obtain$$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{{\left ( \left (1+x \right )^{\frac{1}{2}} -1 -\frac{x}{2} \right )}^{6m}} {{x^n}}}{=\lim_{t\to 1}{\left(t-1-{t^2-1\over 2}\right)^{6m}\over (t^2-1)^n}\\={1\over2^{6m}}\lim_{t\to 1}{(t-1)^{12m}\over (t-1)^n(t+1)^n}\\={1\over2^{6m+n}}\lim_{t\to 1}{(t-1)^{12m}\over (t-1)^n}\\=\begin{cases}0&,\quad12m>n\\{1\over 2^{6m+n}}&,\quad 12m=n\\\infty&,\quad 12m<n\quad, \quad n \text{ is even}\\\text{undefined}&,\quad 12m<n\quad, \quad n \text{ is odd}\end{cases}}$$